# Python Pywin32 - ReadEventLog OverflowERROR

Tags: python, pywin32

I am trying to read out the windows event log using [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/):

```py
machineAdress = None
eventType = "Application"

log_handle = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(machineAdress, eventType)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ | win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(log_handle, flags, 0)
```

Unfortunately, `win32evtlog.ReadEventLog` fails with the following error:

```
OverflowError: days=1757830483; must have magnitude <= 999999999
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
SystemError: <built-in function ReadEventLog> returned a result with an error set
```

According to the [doc](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32evtlog__OpenEventLog_meth.html):

`machineAdress` is a Windows host (e.g. `"localhost"`) and `eventType` is the name of the source of the Windows event logs (e.g. `"System"`, `"Application"`, ...). The error is the same in all cases, only the number of `days=...` changes.

I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows (64 bit). Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are `machineAdress` and `eventType` (post your full code)? Can you post the full traceback (and the line that generates the error - although it seems it's the last posted one)? Please check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also did you check

Comment: Maybe related to https://bugs.python.org/issue11576?

Comment: machineAdress could be one of ten remote Windows hosts (is a multi-thread app) and eventType one the three Windows possibilities (System, Application..). The error is the same in all cases and only show that trace. Of course, the error is in the ReadEventLog line.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Installing [pypiwin32](https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/) instead of [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) solved the problem for me.

- If you installed pywin32 using an executable installer:
  Deinstall pywin32 with the Windows option `Add or remove programs`.
- If you installed pywin32 via `pip install pywin32`:
  Deinstall pywin32 via `pip uninstall pywin32`.

Now run `pip install pypiwin32`. Worked for me with Windows 10, Python 3.7.0 (both 64 bit) and pypiwin32 v223.